# f:viewParam with POST request and redirect

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, mojarra

**Mojarra 2.1.26**

I have a very simple page:

*hello.xml:*

```html
<h:head></h:head>

<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="name"></f:viewParam>
</f:metadata>

<h:body>
    <h1>Hello #{param.name} !!!</h1>
</h:body>
```

And another page *index.html*. On this page I have a commandLink which triggers POST request:

```html
<h:commandLink value="Go to hello page" action="/pages/hello.xhtml" >
    <f:param name="name" value="Hubert" />
</h:commandLink>
```

This works. I can see statement: Hello Hubert !!!

**Question:**

This unfortunately does not work with redirection:

```html
<h:commandLink value="Go to hello page" action="/pages/hello.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" >
    <f:param name="name" value="Hubert" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Could someone explain me why please?

Comment: Have you tried to add in your action parameter `&includeViewParams=true` ?

Comment: @LaurentG, thanks for the hint. This helped me to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question we need to know how redirect works.

**Redirect**

Client HTTP request is received. Reponse for this request is created. It always looks the same.  Code 302 is returned, and header *Location* is set. For example:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: http://stackoverflow.com
...
```

When client received this response then it does another request. This time GET request to URI from *Location* header.

**Question example explanation**

h:commandLink triggres POST request. Response is created. This response contains URI from action:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: http://localhost:8080/myapp/pages/hello.xhtml
...
```

Param name is included, but it is in message body.

When client receives code 302 and Location it does the same as always. Creates GET request:

```
GET /myapp/pages/hello.xhtml HTTP/1.1
```

Simply POST reponse body is ignored. There is no reason to get content from body and attach it to GET request. That's why example from question doesn't work properly.

**Solution 1:** *(based on LaurentG suggstion)*

includeViewParams can be used. But it includes only values from elements *f:viewParam*. So on the same page with commandButton we have to add such element:

```
<h:head></h:head>

<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="name"></f:viewParam>
</f:metadata>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandLink value="Go to hello page" action="/pages/hello.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true" >
            <f:param name="name" value="Hubert" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

So we have *f:viewParam* element on page *hello.xhtml* and this page that redirects to page *hello.xhtml*.

**Solution 2:**

If parameter value is from controller then we can remove element *f:viewParam* from page with *h:commandButton*. Trick can be done inside action method:

```
 <h:form>
        <h:commandLink value="Go to hello page" action="#{controller.action}" />
 </h:form>
```

And action():

```
public String action() {

    String outcome = "/pages/hello?faces-redirect=true";

    try {
        outcome += String.format("&amp;name=%s", URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return outcome;
}
```

**Solution 1 and 2 cretes response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: http://localhost:8080/myapp/pages/hello.xhtml?name=Hubert
...
```

That's what we need.

Comment: That's working but using your sugestion I had another problem. I have a table with multiple selection items. I store these items in a map with element, flag (selected/not selecter)... When I'm invoking the action I loss the map state. My bean is view state and I put a debuging point but never hits, for my surprise the logs writes so I'm entering the method... I don't know whats happening but if you need to "calculate" the value for the f:param value ... fails! but if you hardcode it works.